# InnerJoin MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Tengo problemas para un *inner join* donde me duplica los registros, tengo varias tablas en las cuales aplico,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El *Inner* que  aplico es este:

```
SELECT   
a.codigo,
a.nombre,
a.apellido,
b.calle,
b.altura,
b.depto,
c.telefono
FROM contacto AS  a
left JOIN dire_cont as b ON b.codigo = a.codigo
left JOIN tel_cont  AS C ON c.codigo = a.codigo
left JOIN email AS D ON d.codigo = a.codigo
where a.codigo = TRIM(3);
```

Me genera 4 registros, 2 x los distintos tipos de teléfono y 2 por los distintos tipo de casa, tengo la duda si mi lógica esta bien o es la consulta la que estoy realizando mal.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el resultado esperado?

Answer (score 0):

gusto de saludarte. El resultado de tu consulta se corresponde a las condiciones o valores de los registros involucrados, siendo la columna "contacto.codigo" el único valor usado para vincular con los registros de las otras tablas, el mismo se mostrara tantas veces como registros coincidan, en el caso de "dire_cont" son 2 veces y en el caso de "tel_cont" otras 2 veces, por eso el resultado muestra un total de 4 registros.

Parte de lo que ocurre en que no hay un campo de relación entre lo registros de "dire_cont" y "tel_cont".

Una reducción en los resultados de los registros, podría generarse de esta forma:

```
SELECT
a.codigo, 
a.nombre,
a.apellido,
b.calle AS calle1,
b.altura AS altura1,
b.depto AS depto1,
c.telefono AS telefono1
FROM contacto AS  a
INNER JOIN dire_cont as b ON b.codigo = a.codigo
INNER JOIN tel_cont  AS C ON c.codigo = a.codigo AND b.id = c.id
WHERE a.codigo = TRIM(3);
```

O con esta sentencia, obtienes un solo registro como resultado.

```
SELECT
a.codigo, 
a.nombre,
a.apellido,
b.calle AS calle1,
b.altura AS altura1,
b.depto AS depto1,
e.calle AS calle2,
e.altura AS altura2,
e.depto AS depto2, 
c.telefono AS telefono1,
f.telefono AS telefono2
FROM contacto AS  a
INNER JOIN dire_cont as b ON b.codigo = a.codigo AND b.id = 1
INNER JOIN tel_cont  AS C ON c.codigo = a.codigo AND c.id = 1
INNER JOIN dire_cont as e ON e.codigo = a.codigo AND e.id = 2
INNER JOIN tel_cont  AS f ON f.codigo = a.codigo AND f.id = 2
WHERE a.codigo = TRIM(3);
```

En ambos casos, omito la referencia que se hace de la tabla "email", por que no se selecciona ninguna columna para mostrar, pero si deseas mostrar algún campo de esta tabla solo tienes que agregarla tal y como lo hiciste en tu sentencia.

En función de lo que indicas para la tabla "email", donde no se dispone de un campo de relación, sugiero hacer uso de sub-consultas para emular dicho campo:

```
SELECT
a.codigo, 
a.nombre,
a.apellido,
b.calle AS calle1,
b.altura AS altura1,
b.depto AS depto1,
e.calle AS calle2,
e.altura AS altura2,
e.depto AS depto2, 
c.telefono AS telefono1,
f.telefono AS telefono2,
g.direccion AS correo1,
h.direccion AS correo2
FROM contacto AS  a
INNER JOIN dire_cont as b ON b.codigo = a.codigo AND b.id = 1
INNER JOIN tel_cont  AS c ON c.codigo = a.codigo AND c.id = 1
INNER JOIN dire_cont as e ON e.codigo = a.codigo AND e.id = 2
INNER JOIN tel_cont  AS f ON f.codigo = a.codigo AND f.id = 2
INNER JOIN (SELECT id, direccion, '3' AS codigo FROM email) AS g ON g.codigo = a.codigo AND g.id = 1
INNER JOIN (SELECT id, direccion, '3' AS codigo FROM email) AS h ON h.codigo = a.codigo AND h.id = 2
WHERE a.codigo = TRIM(3);
```

Comment: Gracias por las respuesta compañero , me ayudo mucho el codigo en resumirlo en una linea sola. Tengo otra duda en caso mail, donde no hay relacion para q me tome como correo1, correo2, por la parte de id, donde es autoincremental,

Gracias por todo! Genio!!

Answer (score -1):

El problema es el orden en el cuas estas ejecutando los join recuerda es de tabla padre a tabla hija(Es un decir).

Tabla hija a padre

```sql
left JOIN dire_cont as b ON b.codigo = a.codigo
```

lo correcto es de padre a hija

```sql
left JOIN dire_cont as b ON a.codigo = b.codigo
```

> Es una buena practica usar unos mejores identificadores a tus tablas en lugar de a, b, etc. por ejemplo para dire_cont puede ser `dirc` ya depende pero debe reflejar mejor el nombre de la tabla para que se pueda entender en toda la query

Comment: `A=B` o `B=A` es indistinto, y arrojarán el mismo resultado.

Comment: De hecho no recuerda que estás generando un producto cartesiano donde AxB es diferente de BxA

Comment: En álgebra relacional, en el producto cartesiano AxB, A y B son tablas. Aquí estamos hablando del operador de igualdad donde A y B son columnas, que  establece la condición de selección de tuplas.